# PWA maskable icon overriding larger icons for a splash screen on Android

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I want my PWA to use separate images for the home screen icon and splash screen. I have one 192x192 image and one 512x512 image, the 192x192 icon I want for the home screen and 512x512 for the splash screen.

My manifest.json is as follows:

```
{
  "short_name": "My App",
  "name": "My App",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "background_color": "#0277ff"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "background_color": "#0277ff"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#222831",
  "background_color": "#0277ff"
}
```

This works just fine. It uses the 192x192 for the icon and the 512x12 for the splash screen. But the problem occurs when I add the property: `"purpose": "maskable"` to the 192x192 icon. When I do this, the icon on the home screen looks great, but suddenly the splash screen is now the 192x192 icon and not the 512x512! I can't seem to figure out what I need to do to stop this. Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Besides that, the splash screen was showing the 'maskable' icon, but it was not being masked, leaving all the padding appear on the screen.

I changed my icons array to this configuration, where the 'maskable' icon is an SVG image:

```
 "icons": [
    {
      "src": "mr.ico",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/x-icon",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "mr192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "mr512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "mrmaskable.svg",
      "sizes": "any",
      "type": "image/svg+xml",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ],
```

Testing locally (running on node test server), it was still showing the maskable icon without masking it. But after deploying it (I am using static build), the splash screen icon (mrmaskable.svg) was masked and looked nice.

Comment: cool, worked for me as well with the .svg. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `"purpose": "any"` to the 512x215 icon? I think, this should work. If not, try to configure the 512x512 Icon to be "maskable" too.